# ¿Qué es "ser un membrillo"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, insultos

Ayer caí en la cuenta de que nunca me había preguntado realmente qué significa "ser un membrillo".

Recuerdo, por ejemplo, que en la letra de *Entre dos tierras*, de Héroes del Silencio, dice

> Déjalo ya, **no seas membrillo** y permite pasar y si te piensas echar atrás, tienes mucho barro que tragar.

Y también recuerdo a un personaje de dibujos de mi juventud (ha llovido mucho ya) llamado Chicho Terremoto que usaba la expresión a menudo, como una forma de insulto suave hacia otros personajes.

El DRAE no recoge en la entrada para [membrillo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OrTXSq6) ninguna acepción que no sea la relativa a la fruta.

¿Qué es entonces "ser un **membrillo**"?

Comment: Para mi membrillo (sin ningún tipo de documentación más que mi propia experiencia) sería algo así como pardillo, quizá ingenuo. Como insulto es bastante suave y diría que incluso cariñoso, al menos en la forma que se usa en mi círculo cercano.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para este tipo de búsquedas es cuando viene bien el [Fichero General](http://web.frl.es/fichero.html) de la RAE. Rebuscando entre sus fichas se encuentran muchas veces definiciones de palabras que no han llegado al DLE por el motivo que fuere (ya sea que es una palabra de la que no hay registros escritos -se usa solo en la expresión oral-, ya sea que es una palabra demasiado regional, etc.).

En este caso podemos encontrar las siguientes definiciones:

- Persona tonta, necia, insulsa. [Ribera, Pamplona]. (Fichas [14](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_M/LETRA_M_PDF/MEMBRILLO/00001055.pdf) y [61](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_M/LETRA_M_PDF/MEMBRILLO/00001102.pdf).)
- Enfado, mal humor, gesto avinagrado. (Ficha [113](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_M/LETRA_M_PDF/MEMBRILLO/00001154.pdf).)
- Ser uno agrio como membrillo verde. (Ficha [115](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_M/LETRA_M_PDF/MEMBRILLO/00001156.pdf).)
- Utilizado como insulto, con el sentido de tonto, bobo. (Ficha [142](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_M/LETRA_M_PDF/MEMBRILLO/00001183.pdf).)

Y lo dejo aquí ya, que creo que la idea la hemos cogido. El primer caso, usado al parecer en la región de Navarra, me hace gracia dado que en el doblaje de Chicho Terremoto recuerdo un momento en el que este personaje dice que va a ver a su abuela "que vive en Pamplona" (pedazo de traducción que hicieron en España). Y la banda de Héroes del Silencio es de Zaragoza, que está justo debajo de Navarra, y es muy posible que la palabra en los años 80 ya se hubiera extendido a las regiones de los alrededores (la ficha 61, por ejemplo, data de 1952, mientras que la canción que mencionas es de 1990).

Esto concuerda con lo que yo siempre había entendido que era "ser un membrillo" (tanto en la canción como en la serie): **ser un tonto**.

Comment: @walen estoy dejando al descubierto todos mis secretos... :-D